# Possibility for Multi-layer VPN or queries through TOR?

Tags: vpn, proxy, anonymity

If a user is to fingerprint a server via SQL injection and doesn't want the server to be able to trace back. Is the only way to use a proxy/VPN?

Can queries and requests be sent through TOR network? Or would a user have to use multi-layer VPNs, bounces through different proxies before actual request?

Comment: The answers to this question will vary based on who your target is. If it's your friend's web server, then VPN is probably good enough. If the target can involve law enforcement, then VPN becomes very dubious. If the NSA is involved, then even Tor has questionable value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all queries that can be sent over TCP can be sent over TOR.

Comment: While you answered one of the questions asked in the OP, I believe the OP is actually asking how to use the internet anonymously. You would need to expand your answer significantly to really answer that.